# Richfaces componentControl toggle popup

Tags: javascript, jsf, popup, richfaces

I'd like for a single control to show a rich:popupPanel if it isn't visible, and hide it if it's already visible.

Following through the tutorials and code examples, I've come up with:

```
<h:outputLink value="#" id="loginLink">Login
    <rich:componentControl event="click"  operation="show" target="loginPane" >
        <a4j:param name="event" value="event" noEscape="true" />
        ... more params for positioning ...
    </rich:componentControl>
</h:outputLink>

<rich:popupPanel id="loginPane" autosized="true" modal="false" moveable="false" resizeable="false" followByScroll="false" onshow="#{rich:element('userName')}.focus()" >
    <h:form>
   ...
    </h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Which shows my popupPanel and subsequent form well.  I just can't recognize a way to overload that outputLink's componentControl to hide as well as show.  Naturally "toggle" isn't a keyword - that would be too easy :)  I'm pretty new with JSF and javascript, and have been trying various things for the better part of today.  Can anyone recommend something to get me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I ended up just choosing the lazy route:

I edited the css of the page inline to take the rf-p-shade style not effect alpha and made an onmaskclick event to close the popup.  I could not get it to replicate a "Toggle" like behavior with javascript or jsf notations.

Answer (score 1):

For me the following solution worked, while confirmPanel is the panel in the popup containing the updated data.

```
<rich:column>
    <a4j:commandButton value="Delete" render="confirmPanel"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.show()"
        ajaxSingle="true">
        <a4j:param value="#{record.id}" assignTo="#{showActivitiesAsTableView.selectedActivityId}" />
    </a4j:commandButton>
</rich:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled on this. Hopefully, someone will find my relatively simple solution useful after such a long time:

```
<h:form id="myForm">

  <h:outputScript>
    var popupVisible = false;

    function toggleComponent(component, currentVisibility) {
      if (!currentVisibility) {
        component.show();
      } else {
        component.hide();
      }
    }
  </h:outputScript>

  <rich:popupPanel id="myPopup" domElementAttachment="form" modal="false"
                   onshow="popupVisible = true;"
                   onhide="popupVisible = false;">
    <!-- popup content here -->
  </rich:popupPanel>

  <a4j:commandLink onclick="toggleComponent( #{rich:component('myPopup')}, popupVisible );">
    <h:graphicImage value="/images/some_fancy_icon.jpg" />
  </a4j:commandLink>

</h:form>
```

**Please note:** it only works with a non-modal panel.

You can even have multiple popups, and on onshow() of one popup, you can close all the others. Of course, you need a separate ...Visible variable for each of them.